# Google cloud messaging server side code in java

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

How to implement server side code where the situation is like

Different messages to be sent to different devices based on the type of message.
for example : message type 1 to device 1, 2,3 
              message type 2 to device 1,2,4,5,6
              message type 3 to device 2,4,5,7 and so on

How can I implement the sever side coding for the above case.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: nothing...i just need to start over..i was looking for some reference which could help in java....